# How to convert Texture2DContent to Texture2D in custom ContentTypeReader

Tags: xna, monogame, xna-content-pipeline

I'm trying to implement a custom ContentPipeline extension that writes a Surface object with a Texture2D member.

My input file is an xml with fields for all of my Surfaces and their members. In the xml, my Surface's Texture2D is represented by a path to an image file.
In my ContentProcessor, I want to load the Texture2D from the image file path, then write that texture data straight into my object's xnb with the rest of a Surface's members.

Right now, I've got the ContentTypeWriter writing a different ("CompiledSurface") object with a Texture2DContent member. The Texture2DContent is created in the ContentProcessor using BuildAndLoadAsset(string path).

My importer, processor, and writer all seem to be doing their jobs. But in my ContentTypeReader, I can't figure out how to convert the Texture2DContent back to a Texture2D in order to create my runtime object.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
class Surface
{
    protected Rectangle bounding_box;
    protected Texture2D texture;
    ...
}

class CompiledSurface
{
    public Texture2DContent texture;
    public int x;
    public int y;
    ...
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the code of the content writer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it! An extremely simplified example:

Loaded each Texture2D in custom ContentProcessor like this...

```
// Create external ref to texture source file (.bmp, .png, etc)
ExternalReference<Texture2DContent> tex_ref = new ExternalReference<Texture2DContent>(path_to_image_file);

// Build & Load texture
Texture2DContent texture_content = context.BuildAndLoadAsset<Texture2DContent, Texture2DContent>(tex_ref, "TextureProcessor");
```

Then serialized Texture2DContent in custom ContentTypeWriter like this...

```
// Write as Texture2DContent
output.WriteObject(texture_content);
```

Conversion happens during de-serialization, in custom ContentTypeReader...

```
// But read back as Texture2D
Texture2D texture = input.ReadObject<Texture2D>();
```